# VSTO Outlook Add-in Set a short note/info on Mailitem

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I need to set a short note or info on mail item programmatically.
As shown below for instance.
[image]

I tried with setting a custom mail item category but it doesn't appear on mail item when it is opened. I can only see it in preview.
Setting something like label or tag also works for me. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

That area is not accessible for customization and it does not show any particular property of the selected message,

Comment: Any other way to set a short note on mail item, so that when user opens the mail item he knows something is processed by add-in. Not necessarily in that area.

Comment: You can add a category.

Comment: I want to add the category programmatically, when the mail is in compose mode by user. In the add-in code, I add category and save the mail item, category is not visible on the mail item that's is open and in compose mode. Although I can see category on mail item(in drafts folder) in preview.

Comment: Yes, category is only visible for the received messages, not draft. You can also try to create a form region, where you can display anything you want.